# Using a comma to separate city from postcode

Tags: punctuation, commas, email

I've had an interesting discussion with a colleague around the usage of commas in an address within an email signature.

They claim commas should never be used to separate the city and the postcode. Whereas I believe it makes sense for it to be there as if I were to write a letter each part of the address would be on a new line.

What would be the best practice here?
Some visual examples of how it's currently formatted:

> Business Name, Address 1,
>
> City, Postcode
>
> ---
>
> Apple Sauce LTD, 5 Henry Street,
>
> Manchester, JF34 7TP

I might also add that said colleague only has an issue with the comma being between the city and the postcode. The other commas placement are fine.

Comment: I'm not sure that address formatting is really a question of or about the English language. However, i don't use a comma between town and postcode.

Comment: @KillingTime - I do agree. However, I posted here as it's a question of comma placement. To rephrase, what would be the most grammatically correct way of displaying an address via email.

Comment: I've seen it with both!

Comment: This [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskUK/comments/5njo0e/for_an_address_on_a_single_line_do_you_put_a/) has various suggestions: <<
Linebreaks.

1 Fake Street

London

N1 1AA

If for whatever reason that's not an option then I'd put commas in. ////  Wantang_Bob:

Personal preference.

At the company I work for, we use a pipe delimiter in the corporate colour:

Wantang Bob |
My Job | My Team | My Department |

1 Fake Street | London | N1 1AA |

Desk Phone  | Mobile Phone | Email Address >> I'd say that this is merely an **optional** style choice. Not grammar.

Comment: @GhastlyCode Since an address is not a properly formed sentence, I'm not sure that grammar rules would apply.

Comment: In the US, the US Postal Service has a web site that will convert any address into their preferred format.

Comment: @GEdgar - And it's worth noting that the USPS preferred format never includes any commas.

Comment: You should probably conform to whatever the British Postal Service prefers.

Comment: Note to VTC-ers: This is most definitely _not_ an opinion question; there is a definite objective 'best answer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are treating your email signature as something that will more-or-less be fully or partially cut/pasted for your surface-mail address, you should format your address in the signature the way your national postal authority recommends. As you have used an address in the United Kingdom as an example, I conclude that you are in the UK, and thus that the Royal Mail’s guidelines govern. [The addressing guide on the Royal Mail website](https://personal.help.royalmail.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/81/~/how-to-address-your-mail-%28clear-addressing%29) says explicitly that commas and full stops should be omitted. On that page, there is also a link “Best way to write a UK address” (javascript on the page, not linkable) that will display an [image of an ideally-addressed envelope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sfJe.png). Following that pattern, I would format the sample addresses from your question as

> Business Name
>   Address 1
>   CITY
>   POSTCODE

and

> Apple Sauce LTD
>   5 Henry Street
>   MANCHESTER
>   JF34 7TP

As I am in the United States, I would follow the [guidelines provided by the United States Postal Service](https://pe.usps.com/businessmail101?ViewName=DeliveryAddress), and format a US address entirely in block capitals, thus:

> BUSINESS NAME
>   ADDRESS 1
>   CITY STATE  ZIP

and

> APPLE SAUCE INC
>   5 HENRY STREET
>   MANCHESTER NH  03101

Comment: @AndrewLeach - thanks for the image link.